# Android Studio - Proper termonology for white frame

Tags: java, android

What is the (generally) white frame/box called which often surrounds textviews/graphs etc ?

Example -
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.playconsole&hl=en

I am referring to the white box which surrounds each category eg. : Installs, Uninstalls

How do I do it ?

I want to implement it into my app -
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.codex.csgoconfigdemo.paid&hl=en

Answer (score 0):

That would be a CardView, here's some info about it:

https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html#CardView

Answer (score 0):

I've achieved this effect using CardViews that have the cardElevation attribute.

https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html#CardView